# Can TypeScript infer `this` value correctly in child static methods?

Tags: typescript

I have a scenario where I need a base class with a static method to instantiate the class. This base class is expected to be inherited by some children to have their own set of extra members.

Below is a minimal working example in JavaScript:

```js
class A {
  static create(value) {
    return new this(value);
  }
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  log() {
    console.log(this.value);
  }
}

const test1 = B.create('test1');
const test2 = B.create.call(B, 'test2');
const test3 = A.create.call(B, 'test3');

test1.log();
test2.log();
test3.log();
```

In the static `create` method, it instantiates the class using `new this` so that it will automatically references the immediate parent class.

If it were to be written without using `this`, then all child classes will not be able to instantiate with the static create method because now the logic is locked to `A` only:

```js
class A {
  static create(value){
    return new A(value);
  }
  ...
}
```

So far, so good.

Now, if I were to do this in TypeScript, it failed:

```
class A {
  value: string;

  static create(value: string) {
    return new this(value);
  }

  constructor(value: string){
    this.value = value;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  log(){
    console.log(this.value);
  }
}

const test1 = B.create('test1');
const test2 = B.create.call(B, 'test2');
const test3 = A.create.call(B, 'test3');

test1.log();  // Error: Property 'log' does not exist on type 'A'.
test2.log();  // Error: Property 'log' does not exist on type 'A'.
test3.log();  // Error: Property 'log' does not exist on type 'A'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1oDcwgK4FMBc0EALgE4CWAdgOYDcSKhRYRZw0wJOzOAFBtvkblqASkQNUnIlhIVoFHAHdoRABZkIfTLhF1UAX3qpgAewrESWYERMktAghcpURyVKjUaAdP1zQAvOjaOHrQhoZIoJAwAELQOAAeRDgUACYw8G7QICZUPK4S7GYQJiA4Xjl5nhA+wboM4fSm5kQqOMQAjAHQMV4cXMk8AOTJnUP1zcRtxABM3b393H2YIDwxADTQI+1EM+N0k62jRADM3bB9nEvAK2ub28Qn+-THHRW5+TSoAPTf0ACiJBItgIAAVgQAHHAkIgATy2lSG0FSJna8hMrUSGlaZhUsKhW1gQy8SGOM3eeV0Pz+gOBJDBkOhcIRuSRKLRFAx8QS2OguLhBKGRJJxxOFM+1IBQJB0HBJihMPhQ0RyNRME5mJ5U35+JwhOJQA)

It appears that the type of `this` value is always locked to the root class.

Is there a way I can make the child classes infer `this` correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the snippet in question does not work is because the `this` value within `A.create` is only derived at runtime. Directly inferring it as its parent class is wrong because `A.create` can always be called with a totally unrelated `this` value:

```js
A.create.call(String, 'abc');     // String { 'abc' }
A.create.bind(Boolean)('abc');    // Boolean { true }
A.create.apply(Number, ['abc']);  // Number { NaN }
```

In other words, TS cannot know beforehand the type of `this`, hence inference of `this` value to the parent class is not possible.

This is why we will need:

- [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) to limit `this` to a fixed type (`T extends typeof A`).
- [Type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to explicitly tell TS that the type is `InstanceType<T>`.

```
class A {
  value: string;

  static create<T extends typeof A>(this: T, value: string): InstanceType<T> {
    return new this(value) as InstanceType<T>;
  }

  constructor(value: string){
    this.value = value;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  log(){
    console.log(this.value);
  }
}

const test1 = B.create('test1');
const test2 = B.create.call(String, 'test2');     // Error: StringConstructor is not assignable to type A.
const test3 = B.create.bind(Boolean)('test3');    // Error: No overload matches this call.
const test4 = B.create.apply(Number, ['test4']);  // Error: NumberConstructor is not assignable to type A.

test1.log();
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1oDcwgK4FMBc0EALgE4CWAdgOYDcSKhRYRZw0wJOzOAPACrQcADyI4KAExhEAngAccAewBmcAHwAKIgAsyEAnwA06TLgLFy1AJQEAkhWJgKwHHzm8+qxA1SciWEhTQFDgA7tDauuoY2DiW0JDQdg5OLm78qnSoAL70qMAK9qRYwEQKJFEm+IwWVJbIqKgREAB00bjQALzGMZnQOTlIoJAwAEKCImKScF6oIApU6nXe7AUQCiA4zXMLTa2Vlr399PmF4TjEAIyd0CPNHFyi6gDkopdPB4OrRGfEAEzXt3u3DumBA6gAyqRKFQjC9zkRfu8aA1UAB6VHQACiJBIZQIkJqAGEviRiqUSNBdEEFN9hmQqBQwAAjDbhBThNxwZqfU6vIgAZgBd04wKZlHE6hGCnWXAolmefP5SJR6KxOLx0AAcuyFGgcCQ5mBxNAALbMYBac7hHQwYCg7knYg-IgAFiFQNEzTAslkIGk6k1WBNTP1RgA2nDiC6ngBdA5ojHY3EkAiB4P64mFUklMqUmAUGnxKD0xksnBsjnyLn0PkXLbzRY0IA)